# JToolBarHelper won't work on IE8 and IE9 Browsers?

Tags: joomla1.5, jtoolbar

I'm working on joomla 1.5 and I have this form and it has a Save and Close button but it is not working on IE browsers. The conflict on MooTools.js and jQuery.js is resolved but still the buttons don't work. What is the possible cause of this?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you're asking questions, it's best to provide some code and a specific error message or behaviour; "it's not working" doesn't help us pinpoint what the problem might be.

Comment: "document.adminForm.task' is null or not an object" this is the error. The buttons are working on FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Steps to trace the bug.
1. form name should be "adminForm"

1. all hidden variable present in the form like option, task, view, controller. whatever you are using in your component.